# Rails Error When Deleting User: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

When attempting to delete a `User` in a Rails 6 application, I'm getting the following error:

```
irb(main)> u = User.last
=> #<User id: 43, email: [FILTERED], ...>
irb(main)> u.destroy
   (0.0ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Folder Destroy (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM "folders" WHERE "folders"."id" = ?  [["id", 43]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step': SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey)
/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step': FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (SQLite3::ConstraintException)
```

Most of the solutions I have for this have been to use `dependent: :destroy` and `after_destroy`. As you can see in my `User` model, I am already using both:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :folders, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :articles, through: :folders
  after_destroy :destroy_articles

  private
    def destroy_articles
      self.articles.destroy_all
    end
end
```

How do I delete the User's Folders and Articles when deleting the User?

**Update based on comments**:

```rb
# /app/models/folder.rb

class Folder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :articles

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

```rb
# /app/models/article.rb

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :folder

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :link, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

**Solution**:

The problem was the articles needed to be destroyed before the folders. By changing the `Folder` model as seen below, I was able to accomplish this without errors.

```rb
# /app/models/folder.rb

class Folder < ApplicationRecord

  before_destroy :destroy_articles
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :articles

  private

    def destroy_articles
      self.articles.destroy_all
    end

end
```

Comment: Not sure about the exact issue but does `Folder` have a `user_id` column? The folders delete query says: `DELETE FROM "folders" WHERE "folders"."id" = ?  [["id", 43]]` where it should say `DELETE FROM "folders" WHERE "folders"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 43]]`

Comment: `Folders` and `Articles` both have `user_id` columns.

Comment: I'm with @Deepesh on this one, the query looks suspicious. How does the `Folder` model look like?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the Folder model.

Comment: Should the `dependent: :destroy` not be on the Folder model's `has_many :articles` rather than in the User model? I suspect this is causing it to try and delete an Article using the User id, which of course isn't present.

Comment: I just tested this and when I use the `has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy` option in the `Folder` model, it deletes all the articles when a folder is deleted. I don't want that. In the case that a folder is deleted, all the articles should go to the archive. Only when the user is deleted do I want articles deleted.

Comment: You could try `dependent: :nullify` instead of `:destroy` which would set the `folder_id` on the articles to `null`.

Comment: I tried adding `has_many :articles, dependent: :nullify` to the `Folder` model, but got this error: `NOT NULL constraint failed: articles.folder_id`

Comment: Ah, does the article have a `null: false` DB validation? If so then you could remove that validation and null would be allowed. Assuming that fits your use case of course. If `folder_id` always needs to have a value then that approach won't work.

Comment: No `null: false` on the Article model. I do have `validates :title, presence: true` and `validates :link, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }`.

Comment: So in your schema.rb the `folder_id` column doesn't look something like this? `t.bigint "folder_id", null: false`

Comment: Indeed. I forgot about that. So, I rolled back my migrations, changed the reference to `null: true`, and now the schema is `t.bigint "folder_id"` ...but, I'm still getting the same error, "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed"

Comment: Interesting. Would you mind adding the Article model code as well?

Comment: So what's the use of having the `has_many :articles, through: :folders` on the User model if the Article model has a direct relationship to Users given the `belongs_to :user` on the Article model?

Comment: The idea is to restrict a user from having the same article saved in multiple folders. This was the best way I could figure to do that.

Comment: It seems to me that that should be impossible anyway because an article has a `folder_id` meaning it can only be in one folder at a time. I guess what I'm trying to figure out here is if that `through` relationship is really necessary because it feels like it's not. And if it's not, then you should be able to remove it and put `dependent: :destroy` back on the User model's `has_many :articles`.

Comment: I can't think of another way to do it. The article needs to belong to a User and Folder. I was following the instructions for has_many :through associations on Rails Guides: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Right, having an Article belong to a User and a Folder directly is totally valid and doable without the through association. The Article has a direct relationship to a User because of that `belongs_to :user` meaning the Article itself should have a `user_id` column in the DB. If that's all true, then you can drop the `has_many :articles, through: :folders` on Users and just go with `has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy`.

Comment: In the Rails guide you linked, that `through` is being used to join two tables, `physicians` and `patients` which otherwise would not have any direct relationship to each other because there's no foreign key(s) tying them together in the way that a `belongs_to` relationship establishes. In your case though, it seems like that's not needed because Articles do have a direct relationship to Users and so there's no need to reach through the Folder model to get to Articles.

Comment: I finally got it. I updated the question with a solution. If I destroy all the articles before destroying the folder, it works without errors. You were very helpful in getting me further down the path. Cheers.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.